# Change array back to dictionary - SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a for loop that creates a dictionary and then I append the dictionary to an array. I append the dictionary to an array because I don't know how to add more than one value with the same key, when I do that in the for loop the key / value pair is just updated and the old key / value pair is deleted What is the best way to change the array back to a dictionary?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var jobTitle = ""
    var jobDescription = ""


    var dict:[String: AnyObject] = ["jobTitle": "jobTitle", "jobDescription": "jobDescription"]

    var tArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         for var i = 0; i < 3; ++i {

            jobTitle = "job1"
            jobDescription = "Desc1"

            dict["jobTitle"] = "job1"
            dict["jobDescription"] = "Desc1"

            tArray.append(dict)

               }


        println("\(tArray)")

}


}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what output data you would expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like such, where you have more than one value associated with each key:

```
let jobnames = ["j1", "j2", "j3"]
let jobdescs = ["d1", "d2", "d3"]

var dict : [String:[String]] = [:]

for index in 0..<3 {
  if nil == dict["jobTitle"] { dict["jobTitle"] = [] }
  if nil == dict["jobDesc" ] { dict["jobDesc" ] = [] }

  dict["jobTitle"]!.append(jobnames[index])
  dict["jobDesc" ]!.append(jobdescs[index])
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You call the same assignmenta such as

```
jobTitle = "job1"
```

at every iteration of the loop. Of course the variable will always contain the same value. The same is true for `dict`. It is an ivar, so you keep overwriting it.

What you want is to create a **new** collection of type `[String: AnyObject]` to add to your array.

```
let newDict:[String : AnyObject] = [titleKey : titleText, 
                                    descriptionKey : descriptionText]
tArray.append(newDict)
```